# cannot open shared object file libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: c++

I want to start a process,  but it show "./log/BillServer_err:./Bill/BillServer: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
it can't start! (it is a linux c++ program!)

Comment: Have you found that file?

Comment: yes,/app/mysql56/lig/libmysqlclient.so.18

Answer (score 1):

If the libraries are in a non-standard location, try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path/here` to tell the binary where to locate them.